# Problem with CCAvenue Module - Order not generated after successful transaction

Tags: 8, commerce, payment-gateways

I am using Drupal 8 module of CCAvenue.
For some reason I am not able to get it work, I have used both the modes - Test and Live.
Actually the issue is when I place an order and click on checkout page it redirects me to the CCAvenue test site, once on that test/live site of CCAvenue, I enter my card and other details, then it redirects me to my website but the order is not placed.
So why is the order not getting placed successfully even after successful transaction?

Comment: There is no question here

Comment: @Hudri The question is even after successful transaction why the order is not generated? Do you have any solution to this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please edit the question to include a proper question. Users should not be expected to read the comments to understand what the question is. Any information relevant to understand the question should be moved from comments to the question itself. Also, _any help is appreciated_ isn't a question, but a broad request.